# Layer plots in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, lattice

I need to layer a scatterplot and an `allEffects plot`. Here are some example data:

```
library("effects")
x<-c(1,2,6,7,4,3,5)
y<-c(5,6,3,6,9,4,4)
a<-as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
xyplot(y ~ x|a)
lm.y<-lm(y~x*a)
plot(allEffects(lm.y))
```

To be clear, I would like the `xyplot` layered upon the `plot(allEfects...)` plot. I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `latticeExtra` provides several functions to combine
`trellis` objects: `+.trellis`, `c.trellis` and the `layer`
family. Here you need `+.trellis`:

```
library("effects")
library("latticeExtra")

x <- c(1,2,6,7,4,3,5)
y <- c(5,6,3,6,9,4,4)
a <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2))

pxy <- xyplot(y ~ x|a)

lm.y <- lm(y~x*a)
aef <- allEffects(lm.y)
```

There is a problem with the `plot` method for `efflist` objects
(the result of `allEffects`): it only prints the `trellis` object
but gives no return. The trick is to use the `plot` method for
`eff` objects (the components of a `efflist` object) which is
defined to return a `trellis` object. The effect of your example
can be extracted with `aef[[1]]`:

```
peff <- plot(aef[[1]])
```

And the final step with `+.trellis`:

```
peff + pxy
```

[image: effects with layers]

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the ggplot2 package, which should look something like this.

```
ggplot(data, aes(y=y, x=x)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", fullrange=T) +
  facet_grid(~a) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

It'll allow you to layer plots.

That being said - this isn't a full response since I'm not sure how to incorporate your allEffects() information. Someone else might be able to offer better feedback on that.